# Mongo db C# driver throws exception when mapping complex classes

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having problems with mapping some classes using BsonClassMap.
I've 3 classes like this:

```
abstract class A {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

abstract class B : A{
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class C : B {
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I want only properties visible in the class C to be mapped to database.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<C>(map =>
{
  map.MapProperty(c => c.FirstName).SetElementName("fn");
  map.MapProperty(c => c.LastName).SetElementName("ln");
  map.MapProperty(c => c.Age).SetElementName("age");
});
```

This throws an exception and from what I've manage to find out it seems to be because the properties don't belong to the C class. How should i map this kind of structure ?

Comment: Could you include the exception message and stacktrace, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way class maps work in an inheritance hierarchy is that you register a class map for each class in the hierarchy, and each class map defines only the properties present in that class. So you want to register all three classes like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<A>(map =>
{
    map.MapProperty(a => a.FirstName).SetElementName("fn");
});
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<B>(map =>
{
    map.MapProperty(b => b.LastName).SetElementName("ln");
});
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<C>(map =>
{
    map.MapProperty(c => c.Age).SetElementName("age");
});
```

You can test it quickly with some code like this:

```
var document = new C { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 33 };
Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
```

which outputs:

```
{ "fn" : "John", "ln" : "Doe", "age" : 33 }
```

Or you can use attributes to annotate your classes, which is often much easier, but does require creating a dependency on the C# driver in your data model classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `BsonIgnore` attribute to the properties of class A that you do not want to have stored in the database.  Just add [BsonIgnore] above the property and it will be ignored.

There is also a `BsonIgnoreIfNull` attribute that does just what it says - ignores the element if the value is null.  Very useful in cases where you dont want to null values in the database and waste disk\memory.

Also, you can use the `BsonElement` attribute to change the name:

```
abstract class B : A{
  [BsonElement("ln")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
class C : B {
  [BsonElement("age")]
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```